# How to derive intranet Maturity Model?

Tags: intranet

I am involved in a project for redesigning client's intranet. As a part of deliverable, client is looking for intranet maturity model. Does anyone have an idea what steps to follow while deriving this model?

While re/searching, I found that the term 'Intranet Maturity Framework' (or Intranet Maturity Model) was coined by [Razorfish](http://www.razorfish.com/). The report is available [here](http://www.passageways.com/pdf/BestPracticesIntranetReport.pdf). This report describes different 6 stages in which intranet can be mapped; obviously, next stage would be recommended while going further. But I am not able to relate if I want to map where client's intranet lies in this maturity model and how to derive it.

Is it subjective evaluation performed by some industry expert only? or it can be achieved through user surveys? (If yes, what kind of questions need to be asked in the survey)

Comment: I think is way beyond UX issue. You might want to check a more broader site like Quora. :)

Comment: I'm usually weary of any client who asks for contrived buzz-words as part of their deliverables. Sounds like this client has read enough to only be dangerous. I'd reply with "sorry, I am not familiar with this term, can you provide specifics as to what you are looking and for what purpose?"

Comment: Upon further googling, I can't find any tangible definition that would make sense in terms of it being a UX deliverable in context of an intranet. In terms of software development, they may be asking you which model you prefer, but they are asking in a rather obfuscated way if that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

It is interesting that they are asking for this as a deliverable, because a model is something that you can either physically create or logically design, so what are they after in this case? The first thing I would check with them is just what their expectation is in terms of this model, just so you know that you are on the same page as the client.

A maturity model can be something that is based on industry or published standard (look up UX maturity model if you like) or something that is tailored for a specific organization, generally because the standards don't apply to them specifically. I think you might need something more than a survey to collect the information required to design and implement the model.

Firstly, start with working out who the different types of users are, the information that needs to be collected and stored, the tasks that they need to do on the intranet, and the functions and features they would like. Then you can divide these into what they need, what they want, and what they anticipate in the future. Then you can break these down into finer categories depending on other variables like time, resources, and type of functionality, etc.

It is hard to be specific unless you have more details about the type of company and the information architecture of the intranet, but hopefully this gives you some idea.